# Log4J: problem with isDebugEnabled() method

Tags: java, debugging, logging, log4j

I am struggling with Log4J and isDebugEnabled() method.

When I execute:

```
package org.test;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) { (new Test()).test(); }

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Logger " + logger.getName());
    System.out.println("level: " + logger.getLevel());
    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    System.out.println("level: " + logger.getLevel());
    System.out.println("debug? " + logger.isDebugEnabled());
}
}
```

I get:

```
Logger org.test.Test
level: null
level: DEBUG
debug? false
```

The logger level is obviously `DEBUG`, but `logger.isDebugEnabled()` returns false.
Do you have an idea how to fix that?

EDIT:
I have tried with other versions of log4j and with a `Level` cast, and it did not change anything.

Comment: I'm running this with Log4J 1.2.14 and I'm getting `debug? true`.

Comment: I just ran it on our build too, working fine.

Comment: Do you have a Log4J config file? Please post it here

Comment: I'm getting `debug? true` with Log4J 1.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seems to be a conflict with a dependency introduced through maven.
I have tested to delete some of these dependencies, and it finally worked.
I do not understand why, but... it works!

Comment: I'd hazard a guess you where picking up an older version of log4j from one of those dependencies and it was appearing in the classpath first.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you stop doing `static Logger ....`. there is a [very good article about the pros and cons](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Logging/StaticLog) which is well worth a read, epecially if you are on a server.

Another suggest I'd make would also be to look at [Slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) or [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) if you can consider alternatives. Slf4j for example, doesn't require guard "if" statements around debug logging which in turn means cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce it with this code, but it works for me:

```
package com.example;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTest {

  public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(logger.getLevel());
    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    System.out.println(logger.getLevel());
    System.out.println(logger.isDebugEnabled());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
null
DEBUG
true
```

I've used log4j-1.2.15 for this test.

---

So maybe there's an issue with your version of log4j - switch to 1.2.14 or 1.2.15 for a moment and just check, if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following (from JavaDoc):

```
logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
```

--

The only other difference I see between our examples is you have:

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
```

where I have:

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
```

It's 99% probably not that, but as I said, that's the only difference.

Comment: Yes, I already tried it but it does not change anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's exactly the same as `logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);` (without the typecasting, which the OP already has done).

Comment: Took a stab, just looked at what the documentation said. I have subsequently run the example on our build and it seems to be working fine (with and without the cast).